# The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm new on IOS development and i'm working on a pdf application and i need to store a PDF file on a NSData variable, I have the PDF path but i get this message error when i try to put this pdf on the NSData variable using **dataWithContentsOfFile** her is my simple code :

```
NSError *error;
NSString *PdfPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%@"),document.fileURL ];
NSString *newPath = [PdfPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://localhost" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"OriginalPdfPath => %@", newPath);
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:newPath options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

NB : the pdf path is in this format :    */Users/bluesettle/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/BBEF320E-7E2A-49DA-9FCF-9CFB01CC0402/ContractApp.app/Pro.iOS.Table.Views.pdf*

thanks for your help

Comment: What's `lPdfPath`? Why do you replace the substring? What's the output of newPath at your `NSLog` line?

Comment: I mean PdfPath its just an error and i replace the string because i found that the path need to be without the "file://localhost" prefix and the output for the NSlog is "/Users/bluesettle/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/BBEF320E-7E2A-49DA-9FCF-9CFB01CC0402/ContractApp.app/Pro.iOS.Table.Views.pdf"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cocoa error 260 is a `NSFileReadNoSuchFileError` (as listed in `FoundationErrors.h`), meaning the file could not be found at the path you specified.

The problem is that your path still contains encoded spaces (`%20`), because you're basing it on the URL. You can simply do this:

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[document.fileURL path]];
```

Comment: I removed the %20 from the path using `[lPdfPath stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` the 620 error is gone but i get the NSData = (Null)

Comment: when i use the `absoluteString` i get always the %20 on the path that why i use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`

Comment: @hatimhaffane Ah, sorry, you're right. Post edited to provide a working solution.

Comment: thank you but still get the NSData variable as Null i will try to find a solution

Comment: The current solution definitely works. If you use the method with `&error`, what does it say?

Comment: Then I suppose the file is simply empty. :)

Comment: your code works well i think i have an error on creating the new pdf thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `NSBundle`

```
NSString *newPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"pdf"]
```

### Edit:

Than you can use `bundleWithPath` method, here is an example:

```
NSString *documentsDir= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents", NSHomeDirectory()];

NSString *newPath= [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:documentsDir] bundlePath];
```

Comment: for me I need to use files that are not in the resources folder